# $this->parent convert to php4

Tags: php

I am stuck with a php4 server and I need to convert a script from php5 to php4.

I need to convert this code to php4

```
$response = $this->parent->send('get_content_list', $tail);
```

Thnx in advance.

*UPDATE*
This is the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method: stdClass->send()
```

*UPDATE* I had a __constructor in the parent class. I've changed it to the class name and it is OK!

Comment: Why is that code not compatible with PHP4? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: What class (or framework?) are you using?

Comment: I think you need to look at the send() method and re-write it into a regular php 4 function

Comment: Dont get it... This _is_ valid PHP4 code :? --- `Fatal error: Call to undefined method: stdClass->send()` here PHP4 as well as PHP5 wont help you. You need to bugfix your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am stuck with a php4 server and I need to convert a script from php5 to php4.

Get another host. PHP4 is widely considered a liability, it's way past end-of-life, and you're robbing yourself from many handy features which may decrease development time.

```
$response = $this->parent->send('get_content_list', $tail);
```

So? There isn't a reason this wouldn't work in PHP4, as long as $this->parent is actually defined and an object? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @chchrist: Please reconsider, I am dead serious when I say that converting *back* to PHP 4 will cause more problems than it can possibly solve. Generally, you can: if you explain your customer/boss/host that PHP4 will cost extra *and* is less secure, they're generally sold on the whole PHP 5 thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$response = $this->parent->send('get_content_list', $tail);
```

If this does not work, tell us the error message that you get. If you do not get any error message and it still does not work, set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and turn on `display_errors`

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom: I think that's the point.  The line of code is fine in PHP4.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom Yes, it is. There is usually no need to change anything. There are circumstances where changes are needed (e.g if `parent` is not a member variable of the class), but I prefer not to speculate and wait for the error message instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong and guessing from the error, you are trying to call the `send()` method of the parent class, right?

If so, then I'm afraid `$this->parent` isn't the right way to do so. Try using `parent::send()` or you may also use the parent classname instead of the "parent" keyword.

Your statement may though work if `$this->parent` points to your parent class.

Hope this helps!